# Laravel one to one relationships and query

Tags: laravel, relationship, one-to-one

I have customers who have been classified as (individual - company), I want to get all customer information from the main table and subtable into one query, I tried many times and I did not find a solution to that .. My attempts at the end of this topic

## My tables:

## customer_type

- `id`
- `type`

## customers

- `id`
- `address`
- `customer_type_id`

## customer_individual

- `id`
- `first_name`
- `last_name`
- `customer_id`

## customer_company

- `id`
- `company_name`
- `logo`
- `customer_id`

---

## My RelationShips:

**CustomerType.php**

```php
class CustomerType extends Model
{
    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Customer');
    }
}
```

**Customer.php**

```php
class Customer extends Model
{
    public function customer_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CustomerType');
    }

    public function more()
    {
        $related = ($this->customer_type_id == '1') ? 
        'App\CustomerIndividual' : 'App\CustomerCompany'; 
             // 1 => individual

        return $this->hasOne($related, 'customer_id');
    }
}
```

**CustomerIndividual.php**

```php
class CustomerIndividual extends Model
{
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
    }
}
```

**CustomerCompany.php**

```php
class CustomerCompany extends Model
{
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
    }
}
```

---

I want the output as follows:

```php
[
  {
     "id": 1,
     "customer_type_id": 1,
     "address": "New York",
     "more": {
        "id": 1,
        "customer_id": 1,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "doe"
     }
  },
  {
     "id": 2,
     "customer_type_id": 2,
     "address": "london",
     "more": {
        "id": 2,
        "customer_id": 2,
        "name": "ANA IT Company",
        "logo": "analogo.png"
     }
  }
]
```

---

---

These are my attempts:

```php
return Customer::with(['person', 'company'])->get();
```

---

```php
$customers = Customer::query();

$customers->when($customers->customer_type_id === 1, function($q){
   return $q->with('person');
});

$customers->when($customers->customer_type_id === 2, function($q){
   return $q->with('company');
});

$c = $customers->get();
return $c;
```

---

I hope to find a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to create a new collection and add them to that.

Assuming that `$q->with('person')` is an object:

```
$collection = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

$customers->when($customers->customer_type_id === 1, function($q){
    $collection->push($q->with('person'));
});

$customers->when($customers->customer_type_id === 2, function($q){
    $collection->push($q->with('company')); 
});

$c = $collection->flatten();
return $c;
```

Docs: [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections)

Comment: Undefined variable $collection more... (⌘F1)

"Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$customer_type_id"

Comment: But that refers also to $customer_type_id as undefiend?

Comment: my code: `$customers = Customer::query();
 
        $collection = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
 
        $customers->when($customers->customer_type->id === 1, function($q){
            $collection->push($q->with('person'));
        });
 
        $customers->when($customers->customer_type->id === 2, function($q){
            $collection->push($q->with('company'));
        });
 
        $c = $collection->flatten();
        return $c;`